# Install DB2 Connect under Linux - error occured: "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, db2, awt

I am trying to install db2 connect (Version 10.1) under Linux (Debian 9.5). After calling db2setup the user interface freezes at point 5 (language selection) of the menu. The problem occurs only with the installation type CUSTOM.

This error message is triggered in the /tmp/db2setup.err log when the Next button is pressed.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ibm.db2.install.util.MessageHandler.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.db2.install.util.MessageHandler.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.db2.install.util.MessageHandler.handleError(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.db2.install.gui.panels.FeaturePage.preValidate(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.db2.install.gui.wizard.SetupWizardPanel.preValidatePage(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.db2.install.gui.wizard.SetupWizardPanel.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2029)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2352)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:413)
    at javax.swing.JToggleButton$ToggleButtonModel.setPressed(JToggleButton.java:319)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:263)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:300)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6515)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3332)
    at com.ibm.db2.tools.common.sg.CustomToggleButton.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6280)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2240)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4871)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2298)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4697)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4843)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4503)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4433)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2284)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2724)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:718)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:112)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:677)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:675)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:226)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:689)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:226)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:688)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:222)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:139)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
```

This message appears in db2setup.log:

```
"TSAMP" is needed but cannot be found on the media.
```

What am I doing wrong? I also tried to make the selection with the keyboard only - with the same result.

Is it possible to install db2 connect without GUI?

Comment: Which fixpack of V10.1 are you trying, and if you are *not* already trying with the Fixpack-6 installable image, then download the Fp6 server build and retry.  Also mention in your Question the exact debian build/release, and which jvm/jre/jdk you have (exact version) and bitness details.

Comment: Also, it is possible to install WITHOUT the GUI, by using a *response file*, see the details in the documentation here (and all related sub-pages): https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.qb.server.doc/doc/c0007502.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stackoverflow is for programming issues, you might try dba.stackexchange.com for non-programming matters.

According to IBM [SPCR](https://www.ibm.com/software/reports/compatibility/clarity/index.html), the v10.1 of Db2-connect  was supported on RHEL 5.6 & 6, also SLES 10 and 11 , and Ubuntu 10.04LTS , 12.04LTS.

It might work (or might not) on later versions of Linux, or Debian 9.5 , or might have issues that need workaraounds. You might not get official support via the IBM formal channels. If you intend to use for production, ensure your business formally accepts the risks of running an out-of-support product on operating-system for which it was not tested.

If possible, use a currently supported version of a Db2-connect edition. Check end of support dates with [IBM](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21168270).

Ensure you try with the final fixpack of V10.1 which is FP6 (free [download](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27007053) from IBM - get the 'server fixpack' build fixpack, not the universal one, 
 the server fixpack is installable without needing the base product to be installed already).

Install as root, because non-root installs are troublesome.

Carefully verify all of the [prerequisites](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.qb.server.doc/doc/r0008865.html) especially the required packages, SElinux settings, kernel-parameters and all others mentioned in documentation.

To install without a GUI you have 2 options, either use db2setup with [response-files](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.qb.server.doc/doc/c0007502.html), or use the command-line [db2_install](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0023669.html) tool (deprecated, but still works).  Both tools support additional detailed logging (tracing) which can help, refer to documentation for details.

If you already have a different working Db2-connect server, you can use its [db2rspgn](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0007509.html) tool to generate a text response-file (which you can then edit as needed) and supply the modified response file to db2setup.

If you get installation/run issues, try dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: One last question: is a Java installation on the server necessary? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Only if you intend to use java with Db2-connect.  Refer to https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.qb.server.doc/doc/r0011932.html

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the exception, the TSAMP option must be deselected (installation type: CUSTOM).